# Get path parameter in views-view-fields--portfolio.tpl.php file

Tags: views

I am working on project. In project I am using view. **print $field->content;** parameter print image with link. I want path variable value in variable.

Answer (score 0):

borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685628/drupal-7-get-image-field-path)

// field_video_image is the name of the image field

// using field_get_items() you can get the field values (respecting multilingual setup)

```
 $field_video_image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_video_image');
```

// after you have the values, you can get the image URL (you can use foreach here)

```
 $image_url = file_create_url($field_video_image[0]['uri']);
```